# Trying to pause a css animation by adding a paused class

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I've seen people recomending this method as the best way to pause a css animation. Simply by adding or removing a class where the animation play state is set to paused to or from an element. Here are my attempts:

```css
@keyframes run {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

#animation {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg');
  animation: run .5s steps(6) infinite;
}

.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='animation' class='paused'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

From my understanding, the animation should appear paused in the browser but instead it is running. I've tried adding `!important` after `paused` and I've tried making the class more specific i.e `#animation.paused`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `#animation` is an id selector and it is more specific than a class selector (`.paused`), hence the latter won't override the first.

Replace `.paused` with `#animation.paused` and it will work.

```js
function toggleAnimationPlayState() {
  document.querySelector('#animation').classList.toggle('paused')
}
```

```css
@keyframes run {
 from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

#animation {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg');
  animation: run .5s steps(6) infinite;
}

#animation.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleAnimationPlayState()">Toggle paused class</button>
<div id='animation' class="paused"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that, i wrote it in the question, didn't work :(

Comment: Could you update your [mcve] to actually display the issue?

Comment: That is it. Can't make it more minimal than that. It's complete and verifiable.

Comment: I updated my example to use `background-image`. Let me know if I can be of more help.

Comment: In the initial code you posted, there was a `;` one line above the selector, but it was removed by one of the edits. You might still have that faulty semicolon in your project. Note `;#animation.paused` is **not** a valid selector and neither is `;.paused`. However, you still need the paused state selector to have at least the same specificity as the non paused one or otherwise it won't apply.

Comment: Wow thanks! Tried it today and it works great. Had some trouble getting it to work at first tho so I did some research on toggle and it's the best solution. Sorry for giving you lip yesterday, idak how to add a fiddle on this site yet (real noob here) and i still mouth off sometimes :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this desired effect without needing JS. I would try the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="animation"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#animation {
   width: 256px;
   height: 256px;
   position: absolute;
   background-image: url('spritesheet.png');
   animation: run .5s steps(6) infinite;
};

#animation:hover {
   animation-play-state: paused;
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes run {
   from {background-position: 0px;}
   to {background-position: -1536px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CSS with something like `:hover` or with script.  Here I demonstrate both.

```js
function modifyclass() {
  if (document.getElementById("animation").classList.contains('running')) {
    document.getElementById("animation").classList.remove('running');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("animation").classList.add('running');
  }
  //  document.getElementById("animation").classList.toggle('running');
}
var el = document.getElementById("animate");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyclass, false);
```

```css
@keyframes run {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -1536px;
  }
}

#animation {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg');
  animation: run .5s steps(6) infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

#animation.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#animation.paused:hover,
#animation.running {
  animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  -o-animation-play-state: running;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='animation' class='paused'></div>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="animate" type="button">Do it</button>
  </div>
</body>
```